# Mysteriously invalid OpenGL context in Electron

Tags: c++, opengl, electron, glx

I've created an C++ & OpenGL animation engine backed by GLX and GLEW, wrapped in a Node.js module via SWIG. The goal is to use the engine inside an Electron app in the browser process.

The engine appears quite stable. It's multi-context aware, binding the correct OpenGL context before all relevant operations, checking for errors after almost every possible operation, and backed by a rather large testing suite.

Outside of an electron app everything is working just fine. Mysteriously however, simple scripts that would normally work outside of Electron are failing inside an Electron app in either browser or renderer process.

## Symptoms

- Anything generated by `glGenX` is returning 0
- `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns null, afterward `glGetError` returns no error

## Facts

In this order:

- The OpenGL context is created with `glXCreateContextAttribsARB` with a reasonable FB config. The returned value is non-zero.
- `XSync(display, false)` is being called to wait for X errors. No errors are crashing the program, setting an X error handler yields no results.
- The context is made current with `glXMakeCurrent`, no errors reported by `glGetError`.
- The context is direct, checked with `glXIsDirect`.
- GLEW is initialized with `glewInit`, returning `GLEW_OK`.
- The actions in this case are occurring within the same thread. In the Electron app, the context is made and immediately used in the same process; The creation of the context itself queries the version within the same method. Same symptoms before and after the Electron app is 'ready'.

I'm pretty baffled by this. Everything I'm checking *appears* to suggest the context was created correctly but it otherwise appears corrupted or dysfunctional.

What's going on? What else can I check?

Comment: Node.js is always multithreaded, are you calling into C++ asynchronously?

Comment: More accurately put, all my C++ calls are synchronous. The creation of the context and the version query happen within the same C++ method; Unless Node.js is performing some magic I'm unaware of (and only within Electron?), these actions should definitely be occurring on the same thread.

Comment: How many GL contextes do you create?

Comment: @Luca Only one in this case, but the engine can handle multiple contexts safely.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: I don't think glGetError reports GLX errors. Does the glXMakeCurrent call succeed (does it return true)?

Comment: Does Electron even have OpenGL environment support? My gut reaction (and a brief Google) would be no, but if you can find resources saying otherwise I'll happily rescind my question.

Comment: @geza Indeed. GLX will throw an error unless an error handler is set. I've set up an error handler just in case, and it is also not catching anything.

Comment: @mascoj The issue linked in mikep's answer indicates they don't _not_ support it, if that makes sense. Official or otherwise, an older Electron version did support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8848 reports exactly the issue of a null GL_VERSION and blames Electron version 1.6.1.  The workaround was to roll back to version 1.4.15.

Comment: Boo. That definitely would explain it then, thanks for the research.